# convert a list of tuples to a dictionary and preserve duplicates

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to convert my list of tuples into a dict which contains the values at that location, joined into a list. `dict` does what I want, except it removes the duplicates, which is what I don't want!

Here's what happens:

```
>>> vals
[(5, u'3'), (5, u'3'), (8, u'1'), (8, u'1')]
>>> dict(vals)
{8: u'1', 5: u'3'}
```

Here's what I want to happen

```
>>> vals
[(5, u'3'), (5, u'3'), (8, u'1'), (8, u'1')]
>>> foo(vals)
{8: [u'1',u'1'], 5: [u'3',u'3']}
```

Is there some other python function (`foo` in the above case) that does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easily done using [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
def foo(some_list):
    result = {}
    for k, v in some_list:
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    return result
```

(Using `setdefault` is more efficient than using a `get(k, []) + [v]` as we do the append in place)

Comment: I must admit that this is better than my answer by a long shot. +1

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the popular module collections and **defaultdict** in this matter.

```
from collections import defaultdict
vals = [(5, u'3'), (5, u'3'), (8, u'1'), (8, u'1')]
def foo(lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in lst:
        d[key].append(value)
    return d
print foo(vals)
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {8: [u'1', u'1'], 5: [u'3', u'3']})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
def foo(vals):
    x = {}
    for k, v in vals:
        x[k] = x.get(k, []) + [v]
    return x
```

I use `x.get(k, [])` so that if `k` is already in `x`, we will add put `v` at the end of it, but if it is not, we will put `v` at the end of `[]` and use that for `x[k]`.  A longer, but faster way would be to check first if is there, and if it is, append to it.  This is faster because we don't create a new list each time:

```
def foo(vals):
    x = {}
    for k, v in vals:
        if k in x:
            x[k].append(v)
        else:
            x[k] = [v]
```

You could also do it with a `try-except` block:

```
def foo(vals):
    x = {}
    for k, v in vals:
        try:
            x[k].append(v)
        except KeyError:
            x[k] = [v]
```

Comment: This approach is very inefficient if you're processing large lists as on every iteration you create a new list for the key by copying the old one.

Comment: Much better :-).  The reason `setdefault` is still better for this sort of task (as opposed to your improved version) is that key lookup only needs to occur once.

Comment: @donkopotamus: I definitely see that, and I agree; but I don't think it would be fair for me to steal your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The values of the `dict` should be lists,  which you allocate when the key does not exist, and which you append to if the key already exist.

```
def foo(some_list):
  result = {}
  for k,v in some_list:
    if k in result:
      result[k].append(v)
    else:
      result[k] = [ v ]
  return result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

vals = [(5, u'3'), (5, u'3'), (8, u'1'), (8, u'1')]

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in vals:
    d[key].append(value)
```